# Short novel about a scientist who created microcosm universes and traveled to them

Tags: story-identification, space, novella

Years ago, I read a short novel about a scientist who created microcosm universes and traveled to them. 100 years would pass for each year here.

The scientist would appear every 100 microcosm years -- like an oracle -- making him look immortal.

Later, the microcosm people achieved space flight -- and were about to break into our universe...

Can anyone remember the name of the novel - or the author?

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: _The_ story about a scientist creating a miniature universe where he is considered divine is Sturgeon's "[Microcosmic God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcosmic_God)"

Comment: Maybe I read it in about 1980, not very long - and it may have been older.  There were a couple sequels, as I recall.  The end of the story - shows the microcosm universe inhabitants about to break free -- and expand into our universe.

Comment: One other detail -- the scientist had the microcosm universe in (maybe) a force field - maybe size of a table-top, but observable with a microscope from outside... though time was 100 times faster in the microcosm universe.

Answer (score 8):

Is this ***[Edge of Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11358164-edge-of-time)*** (1958) by 'David Grinnell' (a pseudonym of Donald A. Wollheim)...?

[image: Front cover of "Edge of Time" (1958) by David Grinnell.]

According to this [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3902027998), the premise involves scientists creating a micro-universe where time passes at a much faster rate, in order to observe the birth and death of that universe and everything in-between. The denizens of that universe apparently try to break out at some point.

> This story is from the late 1950's written by Donald Wollheim. And though the characters are somewhat dated, the idea that the story presents is marvelously simple and worth pondering. **What if science could create a micro-universe where time moved at a speeded-up pace, where you could observe the Birth and the Death of that Universe and everything therein from Beginning to End. And what if the denizens of that Universe attempted to break out?** This is Classic SF that touches on the Morality of Science. The SF science is on par what what the author knew of back in the late 1950's not not too outlandish. The idea itself would be translated today under the rubric of "What if your Universe was a Simulation?" An enjoyable light read.

According to this [review](https://bibliomaneblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/ace-double-the-100th-millennium-edge-of-time-a-review/), a magazine dispatches a journalist and a photographer -- named Warren Alton and Margery McElroy, respectively -- to investigate bizarre sightings reported in upstate New York, near Thunderhook Mountain. There, they discover that a group of scientists are conducting an experiment involving the construction of a parallel universe contained within a nuclear-powered magnetic field.

> Grinnell’s *Edge of Time* starts promisingly enough: **residents of small towns in upstate New York begin experiencing waking hallucinations: giant saurians emerging from previously unseen swamps, strange villages laying in wait in valleys, flying reptiles. When Warren Alton and Margery McElroy are despatched by People magazine (but, interestingly, not *that* People, as the latter wasn’t founded until 1974, while EOT was published in 1958) to investigate, they quickly discover that the stories emanate from a particular mountain. On investigation of Thunderhook Mountain, they find that a group of scientists have begun a remarkable experiment, and have constructed a contained parallel universe, which they are studying to learn about the future of humanity.**

Another [review](https://andrewdarlington.blogspot.com/2013/02/vintage-sf-book-review-donald-wollheim.html) notes that Alton and McElroy are captured but then subsequently recruited to document the experiment, dubbed 'Project Microcosm.'

> Alton and McElroy chart a map of strange visions across the Appalachian Coningo County – flights of pterodactyls, mysterious cities in disappearing valleys, even sudden soundless eruptions where previously – and afterwards, there was no volcano. **Plotting the hub of the events, they calculate their point of emanation to isolated Thunderhook, where, after a hair-raising pursuit up unmade mountain tracks they are captured and led into a secure installation. There are threats and bluffing, but eventually it is decided that their writerly credentials make the duo ideal for recruitment to the secret ‘Project Microcosm’, and they are given responsibility for documenting its progress.** In this capacity, the scientific activity causing the region’s mysterious appearances is revealed to them.

For the purposes of closer observation, the scientists apparently have a means of projecting their minds into the bodies of people living within the micro-universe.

> Alton soon finds the history of the project fascinating, researching the formation of planetary systems, then the emergence of early life-forms that stumble through their various stages towards sentience. That, in itself, forms a masterclass in evolutionary biology. But what is even more intriguing is the potential for the miniaturised future within the pocket worlds. **To enable closer scrutiny a means of hypnotically projecting members of the team down into the bodies of people within the microverse is devised. Relativistic time effects determine that subjective months can pass within the experiment as a matter of moments occur within the external world. Gaps of days between projections span thousands of years in the historical development of the tiny planets they visit.**

The photographer, Marge McElroy, repeatedly travels into the micro-universe this way, and becomes known there as the eternal 'Oracle Of The White Star.'

> As a teenager I first encountered this book as a second-hand 1966 Ace paperback, with the haunted green Kelly Freas jacket illuminating an eerie alien planetscape, and the sky-maid ‘Oracle’ reaching out to envelop the White Star. I was impressed. It had trace-elements of that vast mind-blowing immensity which acted as my litmus of good SF. And yes, my mind was blown. But this is a 1950’s novel. As such, it betrays 1950’s attitudes. **Although in many ways Marge McElroy is an aspirational career-woman, full of ingenuity and respected for his skills as a photographer, she still insists on her hair and lipstick being right before she goes into a ‘projection’.**
>
> [...]
>
> **Although initially glimpsed only as the eternal ‘Oracle Of The White Star’, Marge now asserts her presence in a very positive way, using her time within projections to influence events.**

Comment: This wasn't the novel I read much earlier. Interesting and I'm now reading it!